# Can I ask about calculators?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was thinking of asking "What Texas Instrument graphing calculator would you recommend for Calculus 1 and/or 2?"

Is this appropriate? I looked for similar a question, but couldn't find one; even a closed one.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are usually off-topic on SE sites. Also, the answer would be: the model recommended or required in the syllabus.

Comment: I don't recall needing a calculator for anything in my undergrad studies. That included three calculus courses, and a probability course. I did, however, ended up using a calculator twice in exams. In calculus 1, to approximate something and cleverly guess this based on the assumption "they will pick reasonably nice numbers" (which I promptly verified, of course); and once in a probability exam for whatever reason I can't recall.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You haven't done it in the States... Webmaster: calculus courses for engineering majors tend to be rather prescriptive on this topic. Often they ban TI 89 and 92, but allow 83-84. Sometimes all graphing calculators are banned. Or all calculators at all. So the advice from math.SE won't help you much... By the way, you _can_ change your username here. Nothing could be easier.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I see. I have no idea how the engineering level courses go on that matter in Israel, actually. And to think I actually TA'd calculus 2 for engineering students for two years... Hah.

Comment: I TA'd an engineering diff eq course recently, and they still couldn't use calculators.

Comment: I used an 89 often during my first year, found it really helpful for sanity checking integrals and such.  Would recommend it, so long as you don't let it become a crutch.

Comment: I recommend you DON'T get any. I would instead use WolframAlpha. It teaches you to code instead of pressing buttons.

Comment: @Nameless I agree in principle, but W|A is typically not available during  exams/quizzes. Cellular communication is generally prohibited then, while calculators may be allowed depending on the course policy.

Answer (score 6):

There are currently 106 questions on the main site tagged as [calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator), so some questions about calculators are on-topic.

In this particular case, however, it's a lot more borderline: There is a lot of variation between calculus courses, requirements, and whether *any* calculator is acceptable at all for the course. An answer to the question would really be up to university / professor policy, and could potentially be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: I wasn't really looking for calculators that are allowed. At my college, there hasn't been any rules for calculators. I was just looking for a calculator that some users thought were easy to use, had a lot of tools, etc. I like the calculator I have now (ti-36x pro) because it calculates derivatives and integrals, but it doesn't graph. But I don't have experience with any graphing calculators, they all seem confusing to operate, or do A LOT more than I need it to.

Comment: @WebMaster The two components of a *decent* recommendation question are (a) user story: what do you want to do with the calculator? (b) minimum set of features: what it must have, what is preferable, how much is the maximal price you are willing to pay. Make it a question to which answers can be objectively evaluated. If it's just "what do *you* think is easy to use", "what has a lot of tools (but not too many?)", then you'll be inviting votes to close: unclear, opinion-based, etc.

Comment: @WebMaster But I can tell you that when engineering students are allowed to use any calculator they want in a calculus class, they tend to prefer TI-89. It's about same size as TI-83/84, and does both graphs and symbolic calculus. But yes, a lot of buttons.